# Test failure with mockito when testing database

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, mockito, stubbing

I have an android app that needs to be unit tested. I am trying to use Mockito to mock the DBHelper class.

```
public class DBHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DB Utility";

    FirebaseFirestore db;
    CollectionReference cityCollection;
    ArrayList<City> cityDataList;

   
    public DBHelper(){
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        cityCollection = db.collection("Cities");
        cityDataList = new ArrayList();
    }
    public ArrayList<City> refreshDataList(){
        cityCollection.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc: value){
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(doc.getData().get("Province name")));
                    String city = doc.getId();
                    String province = (String) doc.getData().get("Province name");
                    cityDataList.add(new City(city, province));
                }
            }
        });
        return cityDataList;
    }

    public int getNumberOfCities(){
        return cityDataList.size();
    }
}
```

In my CityTest class, I am trying to mock this functionality with stubbs.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CityTest{

    @Test
    public void testCityList(){
        DBHelper dbHelper = mock(DBHelper.class);
        ArrayList<City> cityList = new ArrayList<>();
        cityList.add(new City("Edmonton", "Alberta"));
        cityList.add(new City("Vancouver", "British Columbia"));

        when(dbHelper.refreshDataList()).thenReturn(cityList);

        assertEquals(2, dbHelper.getNumberOfCities());
    }
}
```

But the assertion failed.
`Expected <2> but was <0>`. This is the first time that I am trying Mocking and Stubbing. I have a feeling that I didn't mock the class properly.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: Currently you are trying to assert your mock which has no value. It only has behaviour you explictly give it - it doesn't do anthing else hence zero number of cities. Usually you provide mocks/stubs, which are dependencies of another class, this is your subject under test. This is a real instance whose behaviour you want to test by manipulating your stubs which this class interacts with. Controlling stubs/mocks you can predict/assert expected behaviour of your class under test. Testing this class is currently impossible as you have no dependency injection through the constructor.

Comment: Do you have a link to a tutorial that I could follow? I don't think grasp the Mocking/Stubbing concept correctly.